# C# WebBrowser or Normal Browser

Tags: c#, browser, webbrowser-control

I'm getting "banned" message from a forum site cause of my windows application which tries to connect over webbrowser control by this code:

`webbrowser1.Navigate("http://www.xyz.com");`

I can connect without any "banned" message with my normal browsers both IE8.0 and FireFox 3.6. I cannot find any differences between my application and normal browser. It seems "banned" message is not related my IP address, cookies or header info (User-Agent, HTTP-Accept)

**Please help: How can this forum site realize my request coming from normal browser or application?**

*Note: Sorry for my English. Thank you for your understanding.*

Answer (score 0):

I thing they banned the IP is your system IP not your connection IP who can be change but system IP can not.

some application set their agent like Firefox's user agent then server can't find that the request not come from browser they make them because they need that server can't find somebody going of their site by code not just using browser.

the answer i put nothing match to your question.

Fake identity means i tell about the request make by code inside a application not by browser user use.

the user-agent change make them as normal request that they can't find the request they have come by code not by browser.

Comment: I'm 100% sure that it's not related with IP. So I can browse the page with normal browser. I think site administration made some rules about applications which tries to connect their site :( BUT HOW ? Also can you explain what is "fake request"? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At its most basic you're only sending the following information:

- IP Address
- Headers
- GET data

There *must* be a difference in one of the above for the site to be able to differentiate between the browser control and your actual browser - There's simply no other difference unless multiple requests are involved.

Comment: IP: Impossible. Headers: Seems same. (I compared data on http://aruljohn.com/details.php between normal browser and application.) GET data: Can you please explain what you mean? Thanks.